# Telegram bot which repeats send message with some time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

ClearInterval don't work or work but I make a mistake. I don't know but when I use /stop it continue write 'Sending'. How to resolve such problem.

```js
bot.hears(/\/send|\/stop/, ctx=> {
        let sending = setInterval(() => {
            if (/\/send/.test(ctx.update.message.text)) {
                ctx.reply('Sending:');
            } else if (/\/stop/.test(ctx.update.message.text)){
                ctx.reply('stopping!');
                clearInterval(sending);
            }
        }, 10000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is you're creating new intervals every time you send `/send` or `/stop`. So, your intervals get created multiple times generating multiple intervals in parallel.

Something like this should work:

```
let sendInterval;
bot.hears(/\/send|\/stop/, ctx => {
  if (sendInterval) {
    clearInterval(sendInterval);
  }

  if (/\/send/.test(ctx.update.message.text)) {
    sendInterval = setInterval(() => {
      ctx.reply('Sending');
    }, 10000);
  } else if (/\/stop/.test(ctx.update.message.text)) {
    ctx.reply('stopping!');
  }
});
```